# Scale python UI image without downrezing it (with wxpython, PIL or other)

Tags: python, image, user-interface, wxpython, python-imaging-library

As the title says I have an image in my wxpython interface that is too large, but when I scale it down (either in Photoshop, or using the wxpython/PIL methods) it literally just pixelates it further.

Is there a way to shrink an image to fit the UI but retain its detail?

Using Python, PIL (Pillow), wxPython, but can use anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the tool you are using has a `resample` option, which will change the number of pixels in the resulting image. The resample algorithm decides what will happen when pixels are added or removed.

You can use the `Scale()` or `Rescale()` option on an image in wxpython and state how it should be resampled by using the `quality` argument.
i.e.

```
img.Scale(width, height, quality=wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
```

The `quality` argument will accept the following options:

```
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_NEAREST        Simplest and fastest algorithm.
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_BILINEAR       Compromise between wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_NEAREST and wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_BICUBIC.
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_BICUBIC        Highest quality but slowest execution time.
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_BOX_AVERAGE    Use surrounding pixels to calculate an average that will be used for new pixels.
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_NORMAL         Default image resizing algorithm used by wx.Image.Scale .
wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH           Best image resizing algorithm.
```

Based on your comment, here is a simple example.
Just resize the window for the images to track the change in window size.

```
import wx

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = "Resize This Window", size = wx.Size( 500,300 ))
        bSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        self.img1=wx.Image("bgimage1.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.img2=wx.Image("bgimage1.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.m_bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(self.img1))
        self.m_bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(self.img2))
        bSizer.Add( self.m_bitmap1, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0 )
        bSizer.Add( self.m_bitmap2, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0 )
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onResize)
        self.SetSizer( bSizer )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def onResize(self, event):
        frame_size = self.GetSize()
        frame_h = (frame_size[0]-10) / 2
        frame_w = (frame_size[1]-10) / 2
        img1 = self.img1.Scale(frame_h, frame_w, quality=wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        img2 = self.img2.Scale(frame_h, frame_w, quality=wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        self.m_bitmap1.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img1))
        self.m_bitmap2.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img2))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Layout()

app = wx.App()
MyFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is the solution I've read everywhere but I still can't get it to work. I get this error: 

`AttributeError: 'Bitmap' object has no attribute 'Scale'`


I've tried pretty much every variation on this to no avail: 


`image_file.Scale(200, 200, quality=wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)


image_file = wx.Image('bgimage.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()


`